# jsonp jquery getting instagram results Cannot read property 'link' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am seeing an error in the console and I am not sure how to resolve it, I am getting the error:

> Cannot read property 'link' of undefined

However it is working fine pulling the images and the links so a little lost...

any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=266454510.1677ed0.f66c5bc93aed4040a9392cdebfae5d63&count=9",
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //console.log(data.data[i]);
            $(".instagram-photos").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + "'></img></a>");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Check if `data.data[i].link` is available for all your test cases.

Comment: can you include a sample of `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `for` loop is not checking if the elements exists in array. You're assuming that there will be always **10** elements in the `data` array. However, sometimes, there might be less than 10 elements and your loop will fail. Make the condition in the loop more dynamic.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Code Here
}
```

Should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is find out which of those properties is undefined, and why it is.

Things that could be undefined :

- `data`
- `data.data`
- `data.data[i].link`

This could also have to do with your for loop, why are you asuming your `data.data` is the length of 10?

See :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Why not use

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
```

Also a little opinion of me, why are you using `data.data`? this is really confusing.
You should use either `data.item[i]` or give the first `data` another name.
This is not a MUST but it sure is a Should if you want other people to "like" your way of coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are only 9 `link` properties.

You've to modify loop like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
```